# Building chromium under windows: ninja -libpath doesn't recognize space (even in quoted path!)

Tags: windows, chromium, visual-studio-2019, ninja, lld

Following all prerequisites and instructions from here
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Build-Chromium

When I'm finally getting to the building part:

> autoninja -C out\Default chrome

I receive error:

> Files\SQLXML: no such file or directory
>   lld-link: error: lib failed

Apparently -libpath argument is not parsed correctly despite it's in quotes:

> "-libpath:C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\"

The failing command:

> ninja: Entering directory `out\Default'
>   [18 processes, 68/41674 @ 17.3/s : 3.9...ic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.lib
>
> FAILED: obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.lib
>   ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ....\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe /lib /nologo "-libpath:D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "-libpath:D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\lib\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" "-libpath:D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "-libpath:D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\lib\x86" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" "-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLXML 4.0\bin\" "-libpath:C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\" /ignore:4221 /llvmlibthin /OUT:obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.lib @obj/base/third_party/dynamic_annotations/dynamic_annotations.lib.rsp
>
> Files\SQLXML: no such file or directory
>
> lld-link: error: lib failed

Comment: Looks like you have added your own code in `third_party` folder, cause `dynamic_annotations` is not a third-party dependency of Chromium. You should post the contents of `build.gn` so that we can analyze further

Comment: @Asesh no, nothing added, pure code from repo

Answer (score 1):

After executing "gn gen out/Default" command open "out/Default/toolchain.ninja" file and quote path inside -libpath parameter once more with single quotes in all occurrences on SQLXML reference:

```
"-libpath:'C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLXML 4.0\bin\'" "-libpath:C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\"
```

for some reason only references to SQLXML required this change

Comment: This is working for me `"-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLXML 4.0\bin\"` replace with `"-libpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLXML 4.0\bin"`